# How can I write this query

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

### id  user_id    titel

```
1   user_id1   a
2   user_id2   b
3   user_id1   c
4   user_id3   d
5   user_id1   e
6   user_id2   f
7   user_id4   g
8   user_id3   h
9   user_id1   j
10  user_id1   i
```

I need select 5 first title that they have not user_id3 and ordered by id  ASC and in the end of table add all they have user_id3.

result:

```
user_id1   a
user_id2   b
user_id1   c
user_id1   e
user_id2   f
user_id3   d
user_id3   h
```

Comment: Your english is very difficult to understand. Could you check your grammar? Also, you have not specified the name of the table which is required for this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id!='user_id3' ORDER BY id LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id='user_id3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE user_id!='user_id3'
UNION SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE user_id='user_id3'
ORDER BY IF(user_id='user_id3', 1, 0) ASC,  id ASC
```

Note that the `order by` must be at the end of the query, so you have to use this kind of tip to do what you want. If you assume that your id are already sorted (which requires no deletion), you could delete the whole line, because union add the second request results after the first ones.